# K-Largest elements Algorithm Comparison

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, heap

I am trying to extract the k largest elements from a large array and compare the following 2 algorithms

1. Min Heap Method. `T(n) = k + nlogk`
2. Sorting Method. `T(n) = nlogn`

But due to some reason Algorithm 2 is performing better. Can someone please explain why

```
import math


class MinHeap:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.__items = arr
        self.build_heap()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.__items)
def items(self):
    return self.__items

def build_heap(self):
    for node_number in xrange(int(len(self.__items) / 2), 0, -1):
        self.heapify(node_number)

def heapify(self, node_number):
    # return if leave node
    if node_number > int(len(self.__items) / 2):
        return

    node = self.__items[node_number-1]
    left_child = self.__items[(2 * node_number)-1] if (((2 * node_number)-1) < len(self.__items)) else None 

    right_child = self.__items[(2 * node_number + 1)-1] if (((2 * node_number + 1)-1) < len(self.__items)) else None        

    min_node = node

    if left_child != None and right_child != None:
        min_node = min(node, left_child, right_child)
    elif left_child != None :
        min_node = min(node, left_child)
    elif right_child != None :
        min_node = min(node, right_child)

    if min_node == node:
        return
    elif left_child!=None and min_node == left_child:

        self.__items[node_number - 1], self.__items[(2 * node_number)-1] = self.__items[(2 * node_number)-1], self.__items[node_number - 1]
        self.heapify(2 * node_number)
    elif right_child!=None and min_node == right_child:

        self.__items[node_number - 1], self.__items[(2 * node_number + 1)-1] = self.__items[(2 * node_number + 1)-1], self.__items[node_number - 1]
        self.heapify(2 * node_number + 1)

def extract_min(self):
    length = len(self.__items)
    if length == 0:
        return
    self.__items[0], self.__items[length-1] = self.__items[length-1], self.__items[0]
    min_element =  self.__items.pop()
    self.heapify(1);
    return min_element

def insert(self, num):
    self.__items.append(num)
    current_node = len(self.__items)
    parent_node = int(current_node / 2)
    while current_node > 1:
        min_node = min(self.__items[current_node-1], self.__items[parent_node-1])
        if min_node == self.__items[parent_node-1]:
            break
        self.__items[current_node-1], self.__items[parent_node-1] = self.__items[parent_node-1], self.__items[current_node-1]
        current_node = parent_node
        parent_node = int(current_node / 2)

# Comparing Algorithms ::::::::::::::::::
import time
import random
from min_heap import *

numbers = random.sample(range(100000), 50000)

k = 3
n = len(numbers)

# k Largest element using Heap T(n) = k + nlogk
start = time.time()
my_heap = MinHeap(numbers[:k+1])

for number in numbers[k+1:]:
    my_heap.extract_min()
    my_heap.insert(number)

data =  sorted(my_heap.items(),reverse=True)
print data[:len(data)-1]
end = time.time()
print "Took {} seconds".format(end-start)


# k Largest element using sorting T(n) = nlogn
start = time.time()
sorted_arr = sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
print sorted_arr[:k]
end = time.time()
print "Took {} seconds".format(end-start)
```

This is the output that I am getting:

Algorithm 1

```
[99999, 99998, 99997]
Took 0.15064406395 seconds
```

Algorithm 2

```
[99999, 99998, 99997]
Took 0.0120780467987 seconds
```

Comment: Probably because Python is slow. (language overhead)

Comment: import heapq and use python's heapify. If it is reasonably close to sorted, but your algorithm is not, then you might have an issue in your heapify

Comment: @KennyOstrom It seems like you are correct about my MinHeap class not being optimised. I am getting the expected results when I am using python's heapq module. Can you suggest any optimisations for my MinHeap class ?

Comment: The correct answer (imho) is don't rewrite the standard library - just import heapq. You have some good points on your implementation in one answer, and some algorithm improvements in another. And you can post it to stackreview for in depth optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theoretical bounds are:

- Sorting: O(n log n)
- heap selection: O(n log k)
- [quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect): O(n)

One of the problems with your heap selection method is that you're creating a heap of the entire set of items. You really only need to create a heap of the first k items. The algorithm is:

```
h = create a min heap of first k items // O(k)
for each remaining item
    if item is larger than smallest item on heap
        remove smallest item from heap
        add new item to heap
```

The worst case for that algorithm is O(n log k). The idea is that in the worst case you end up doing n insertions and n removals from a heap of size k. In the average case, the number of insertions and removals is quite a bit smaller. It depends on the relationship of k to n. If k is much smaller than n, this method can be very fast.

In your code, you're creating a min-heap of the first k items, and then you have this loop:

```
for number in numbers[k+1:]:
    my_heap.extract_min()
    my_heap.insert(number)
```

That code will not reliably produce the correct result because you're unconditionally removing the minimum element. So if the heap already contains the top k elements, but you still have numbers left, it will replace a larger element by a smaller one. You need to modify your code:

```
for number in numbers[k+1:]:
    if (number < my_heap.get_min())  // get_min returns the minimum element, but doesn't remove it
        my_heap.extract_min()
        my_heap.insert(number)
```

Not only will that give you the correct answer, it will reduce the number of insertions and removals you have to make in the average case, which will speed up your program.

Your heap implementation also is non-optimum. You'll save considerable time making your `heapify` function iterative rather than recursive, and there are ample opportunities for you to optimize that function.

As I mentioned above, quick select is an O(n) algorithm. In general, quick select is faster when k is more than about 2% of n. So if you're selecting 100 items from a list of 1,000, quick select will almost certainly be faster. If you're selecting 100 from a list of 1,000,000, then the heap selection method should be faster.

Sorting shouldn't ever be faster than quick select, and it shouldn't be faster than heap selection unless you're selecting a very large percentage (more than 60%, I expect) of the items.

I did some fairly detailed analysis of this a few years back. See my blog post, [When theory meets practice](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/).

Comment: @KennyOstrom No, they don't. If you have a heap of k items, and the next item you're looking at is smaller than the smallest item already on the heap, then you don't need to add it to the heap. In the *worst case* (if the items are sorted in ascending order), then every item ends up having to go onto the heap. In the best case (items are sorted in descending order), only the first `k` items go onto the heap. In the average case, fewer than 50% of items go onto the heap.

Comment: Ah, I see, "in the case where k is small" (which was not given) then it may be beneficial to keep the heap tiny and maybe skip a lot of the inputs with one comparison (versus an O(n) heapify).

Comment: @KennyOstrom In the average case, the method I describe is faster than creating a heap of all n items. Quickselect is normally faster than heap selection, except when k is a very small percentage of n.

Comment: @JimMischel Actually I am creating a heap on the first k items only by using `my_heap = MinHeap(numbers[:k+1])` but it seems like my MinHeap class is not optimised. I am getting the expected results when I am using python's heapq module. Can you suggest any optimisations for my MinHeap class ?

Comment: @Aakash see my update. There's a bug in your program.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for pointing that out. I'll make the heap using k+1 elements, that will ensure that I have k largest elements at the end. And I'll try to measure the performance after switching to iteration. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the answer:

1. Practical aspect:

   Calling user defined function is often slow, growing lists requires re-allocation of memory, etc. None of that counts in the "`sort()` + `[:k]`" approach. Python code can be slow if the author doesn't pay attention to the details of memory management. So you're measuring differences in implementation AND differences in the algorithm.
2. Theoretical aspect:

   I don't know how you came up with `T(n) = k + nlogk` for the min heap method, but I see you calling `my_heap.insert()` and `my_heap.extract_min()` (triggering `heapify()`) almost `n` times. Both are logarithmic in `n`, so it looks more like `nlog(n)` in total.

---

Here's the output of a profiler run:

```
$ python -m cProfile -s cumtime h.py | head -n 20
[99999, 99998, 99997]
Took 0.255105018616 seconds
[99999, 99998, 99997]
Took 0.0103080272675 seconds
         800007 function calls (750010 primitive calls) in 0.291 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.022    0.022    0.291    0.291 h.py:1(<module>)
    49996    0.034    0.000    0.144    0.000 h.py:47(extract_min)
99995/49998  0.088    0.000    0.103    0.000 h.py:17(heapify)
    49996    0.076    0.000    0.090    0.000 h.py:56(insert)
        1    0.018    0.018    0.021    0.021 random.py:293(sample)
   149975    0.015    0.000    0.015    0.000 {min}
   299987    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 {len}
        2    0.010    0.005    0.010    0.005 {sorted}
    49996    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
    49996    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
    50000    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
```